# How to get SQLite3 in the pkg-config search path so I can build Postler from source?

Tags: build, sqlite, ubuntu-11.10

I'm trying to build Postler from source. I branched it from bzr, and the first step in the install process says to navigate to the postler folder and type "./waf configure", which I did. Upon typing that, it runs a bunch of checks and decides SQLite3 isn't in the pkg-config search path. How do I get it in the search path? I already installed it via `sudo apt-get install sqlite3`.
I'm running Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 21):

You need to install the development package via `sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use dpkg

```
 dpkg -L sqlite3
```